# Is it possible to tell Asterisk to not validate registrations using pjsip?

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk 14 with pjsip.  I would like to disable authentication requirements for certain users, so when that user registers I don't have to send the "REGISTER" request twice (the second containing credentials).  I am not sure where to do this using pjsip.

Thank you

Comment: you want to send REGISTER every time without credential("Authorization") header? It means Every time server will reply 401 Authorization message, If you send REGISTER message without credential.

Answer (score 0):

On first register server send back nonce, which used for encrypt password on second attempt.

So no, it is not possible do secure registration without that.

But yes, you can patch any channel driver and do whatever you want with it. Sure you also have patch clients acordinly.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!